# Image resolution low after converting pdf to image using GraphicsMagick for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to convert pdf into image using [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) package and i just can't understand how should i adjust the output resolution.

If i'm doing like this:

```
 gm(`${sourcePath}[0]`)
      .setFormat('jpg')
      .stream()
      .pipe(writeStream);
```

The output quality here is very low, so i'm trying to use `density(594, 842)`
like this:

```
gm(`${sourcePath}[0]`)
      .setFormat('jpg')
      .quality(100)
      .density(595, 842)
      .stream()
      .pipe(writeStream);
```

but doing this the image looks very starchy.

Can anyone please point me what should i do in order to receive the
output image close as possible to the pdf source using the npm package?

Or maybe recommend me about a different library that i can use for converting pdf to image (before ocr)

Comment: I don't really use GraphicsMagick much, nor `node.js` at all, but I do know that with **ImageMagick** at least you must set the density **before** you load the image...

Comment: Specifically `magick -density 288x288 INPUT.PDF result.png`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The thing is that there a lot of examples how to do it from the command-line but no examples how to do it inside the code and apperently its working differently.